# The buttons on my form are not showing up

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a help to make this code to work...I don't know what I'am doing wrong here. I'am making a program with many buttons in Windows form application. I'am with three classes, Form1.cs, easy.cs and Methods.cs. The Form1 class is just so you can click on a button to get another window up, like if you click on easy the easy class will pop up. I had created my buttons in the Methods class (see the code below). Now, here is the thing, I want to get the functions from my class Methods, it seem to be working but there is one thing, the buttons do not show. The function fylla_takka in Methods.cs is supposed to create the buttons, I guess it does, but doesn't show them. then the butt_click function, that is just that happens when you click on a button. I want to have these things in a class so I can use it again and again.
Sorry for commenting in Icelandic in my code, but I didn't expect to show the code to someone else :)

Form1.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Samstæðuleikur
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

            }


            easy easy = new easy();
            public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                easy.Show();   
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }



        }
    }
```

easy.cs:

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samstæðuleikur
{
    public partial class easy : Form
    {
        public easy()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Methods methods = new Methods();
        private void easy_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            methods.fylla_takka(3,3);//This one is working
        }
    }
}
```

Methods.cs:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samstæðuleikur
{
    public partial class Methods : Form
    {
        public Methods()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       int counter = 0;
       int teljari = 0;
       int counter2 = 0;
            Random rand = new Random();//Ný random tala
             int ragdomly_easy = 0;
             int ragdomly_easy1 = 0;
            int ragdomly_easy2 = 0;
            int snowy1 = 0;
            int snowy2 = 0;
            int snowy3 = 0;

        public void ragdmomly(int endir)//Bý til fall sem velur 3 random tölur frá 1 upp í enda
        {

            ragdomly_easy = rand.Next(1, endir);
            ragdomly_easy1 = rand.Next(1, endir);
            ragdomly_easy2 = rand.Next(1, endir);
            int snowy1 = ragdomly_easy;//Planta fyrsta snowy
            int snowy2 = (ragdomly_easy1);//Annað snowy
            int snowy3 = (ragdomly_easy2);//Þriðja snowy
        }




        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();//Skilgreini lista svo ég get haft eins marga takka og ég vil!
        public void fylla_takka(int lengd, int fjoldi)//Býr til takkana, eins marga og ég vil!
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Testing if my function works, you see this message so it's working.");
            int x = 50;
            int y = 35;


            for (int i = 0; i < fjoldi; i++)//Keyri hve_margir_takkar sinnum yfir listann
            {
                teljari++;
                buttons.Add(new Button());//Set takkann í listann svo að það sé hægt að velja ákveðinn takka
                buttons[i].Location = new Point(x, y);//Vel frá listanum takka nr i og gef honum staðsetningu x og y
                buttons[i].Size = new Size(50, 50);//Vel frá listanum takka nr i og breyti stærð hans

                x = x + 50;//Takkinn, næst þegar lúppan keyrir, fer 35 til hliðar.

                if (teljari == lengd)//Hversu margir takkar eiga að vera í hverri röð
                {
                    y = y + 50;//Ef að lengdinni er náð þá förum við í næstu línu
                    x = 50;
                    teljari = 0;
                }

                this.Controls.Add(buttons[i]);// <-- Something may be wrong here, the buttons are not showing up Set takkann á formið, lúppan keyrir x mörgum sinnum og þá koma x margir
                //takkar
                buttons[i].Click += new EventHandler(butt_Click);//Ef ýtt er á takkann þá fer forritið í
                //eventHandlerinn butt_Click
                buttons[i].Name = i.ToString();
                counter++;
                counter2++;
            }

        }


       public void butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Eventhandlerinn butt_Click
        {

            Button temp = (Button)sender;//Ef að eitthvað gerist í takkanum þá gerist eventið s.s. allt sem er inn í butt_Click
            //í þessu tilfelli.


            for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; i++)//Keyri í gegnum takka listann
            {

                if (temp.Name == Convert.ToString(snowy1))
                {

                    temp.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    temp.Text = "Snowy";
                }

                else if (temp.Name == Convert.ToString(snowy2))
                {
                    temp.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    temp.Text = "Snowy";
                }

                else if (temp.Name == Convert.ToString(snowy3))
                {
                    temp.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    temp.Text = "Snowy";
                }


                else
                {
                    temp.BackColor = Color.Red;//Breyti litnum í rauðann
                    counter2++;
                }
            }
            if (counter == 120)//Þegar ýtt er á takka þá bætist alltaf 30 við því takarnir eru 30 30*3=120
            {

                MessageBox.Show("SNOWY!");
            }

            if (counter2 == 840 || counter2 == 720)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, No Snowy.");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I hope someone out there could help :)

Comment: Is your methods class suppose to create buttons on your easy form class?

Comment: You got three Forms (Methods, easy and Form1). When you click on the Button in Form1 the easy-Form will apear and create an Object of Methods, but It will not be showed because you missend "methods.Show()".

Comment: As @Lee mentions, you don't seem to be calling methods.Show() anywhere. Is it missing from your code sample ? Is your Methods form showing at all ?

Comment: Wow... How could I not have seen that? Problem solved. Wow..I'am an idiot sometimes :( Thx for your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was, that I was calling a wrong class in one of my form. The easy.cs doesn't even have to be there! Then I can use this again and again. The correct solution is then:

```
Methods methods = new Methods();//Take a "copy" of the class Methods
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//When button is clicked:
    {
        methods.Show();
        methods.fylla_takka(3, 3);//This one is working  
    }
```

and we don't have to use the easy class, and the Methods class remains unchanged.

Answer (score -2):

Typically when controls are added to the layout they are done in the InitializeComponent() function.  You don't have to do it there but if you look at that built int function you will see that the calls to `this.Controls.Add( )` are surrounded by suspending and resuming the layout.  These are expensive calls so to minimize try wrapping your entire for loop in them:

```
this.SuspendLayout();

for (int i = 0; i < fjoldi; i++)//Keyri hve_margir_takkar sinnum yfir listann
{
  . . .

this.Controls.Add(buttons[i]);

. . .

}

this.ResumeLayout(false);
this.PerformLayout();
```